# Can jquery animations be chained programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I have this code:

```
jQuery('#flash').animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200)
                .animate({opacity: 0}, 200)
                .animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200)
                .animate({opacity: 0}, 200)
                .animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200)
                .animate({opacity: 0}, 600)
```

and I'm not decided on how many times I want its state altered. Is there a way to chain animations programmatically instead having to add/remove chain elements by editing the animate chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't chain animations without editing the animation queue. If you want to chain a variable, but limited number of times you can do easily with a loop:

```
var flash = $("#flash");
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
    flash.animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200).animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
```

If you want an endless loop, or one that stops when a condition is to be fulfilled in the future, you want to hook a callback on the animation queue, restarting the function:

```
var flash = $("#flash");
function anim() {
    // if (condition)
    flash.animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200).animate({opacity: 0}, 200, anim);
                                            // call "recursively": ^^^^
}
anim();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you only need a FOR loop:

```
function animate_n_times(n) {
   var flash = $('#flash');
   for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
      flash.animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200)
           .animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
   }

}
```

then called like:

```
animate_n_times(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the animation using a loop if that's what you're looking for.

```
var $flash = jQuery('#flash'), i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $flash = $flash.animate({opacity: 0.35}, 200)
                   .animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter alternative, using the extension [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/):

Animate a given number of times:

```
$('#flash').repeat().animate({opacity:0.35}, 200)
    .animate({opacity:0}, 200).until(10);
```

As endless loop:

```
$('#flash').repeat().animate({opacity:0.35},200).animate({opacity:0},200,$);
```

For details see the API of [.repeat()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/repeat/.repeat.html), [.until(count)](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/repeat/.until_count.html), and [.animate(…,$)](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/animate/.animate_timed.html).