# Repeat function infinite number of times

Tags: javascript, function, intervals, infinite

Based om some earlier questions I try to run my function a infinite number of times.
But still it doesn't work.
If I run the script, it get broken on strange moments en before running the script again there is a long interval. 
Can anyone help me to get this script running without intervals and stops? 
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#go").hide().ready(function(){
animatie();
});
var d = 0;
function animatie() {
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  var b = ".block"+i;
  $(b).hide().delay(d).fadeIn(2000);
  $(b).hide().delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
  d += 4000;
 }
}
window.setInterval(animatie, 13000);
</script>
```

Comment: could you define "gets broken" ?

Comment: duplicate of [Can jquery animations be chained programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436701/can-jquery-animations-be-chained-programmatically) or [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4713477/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to reset `d` to `0` each time the `setInterval` triggers. Also, maybe the `4000` should be `5000` instead (`2000 + 1000 + 2000`). Lastly, you don't need to `.hide()` twice: http://jsfiddle.net/nZHCB/.

```
function animatie() {
 var d = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  var b = ".block"+i;
  $(b).hide().delay(d).fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
  d += 5000;
 }
}
animatie();
window.setInterval(animatie, 15000);
```

That said, you can also use one function to iterate over an element. When the last animation (`.fadeOut`) is done, call the function again with the next element: http://jsfiddle.net/nZHCB/2/.

```
$("div").hide();

(function animatie(i) {
    var b = ".block" + i;
    $(b).fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        animatie((i + 1) % 3);
    });
})(0);
```